# JavaScript Loading Bar that Shows Asset Filenames as a Website Loads Individual Assets?

Tags: javascript, http, progress-bar, loading

I'm trying to create a percentage loading bar in JavaScript that shows the filenames as the assets load, my question is how? For example, if I have 10 files on my server to fully render index.html, when the browser loads one of those files, I want my progress bar to show the filename and say 10%.

I first tried to think I could accomplish this with HTTP response headers, but just because a browser receives a response from a server, doesn't mean they instantly have the file ready to render, right?

Comment: Rendering is usually a much quicker part of the process, the really slow part are the network requests - so I think rendering time would be rather negligible here. // But I don’t think this provides any actual value to the user, it sounds like a mere gimmick to me ...

Comment: Can you post your code for requesting the files?

Comment: I'm yet to write code, but after some research, I think I can accomplish what I want with the following:

object.onload = function(){myScript};

So basically, I'm going to attach this to every object that would send an HTTP request like an image, a script, a font, etc. Then as the object loads, I'm going to add a percentage to the loading bar and display the filename of what's being loaded, so if I have 10 files and 1 loads, loadingBarWidth = loadingBarWidth + 10%. 

This way, I'll have a loading bar that's more than a gimicky spinning loading gif that fades on document load :).